# Find smallest three values in Excel table, in unique row and column

Tags: lambda, datatable, formula, unique, excel-365

The table (table1) is below.

[image]

The desired output is the smallest N values **which are not in the same column or the same row as each other**.

Let's say in this case N is 3, so we want the smallest 3 values which are in a unique column and row. These value are:

```
1
6
4
```

Note that N could be any number, not necessarily 2.

The formula

```
=SMALL(Table1,{1,2,3})
```

would return

```
1
2
3
```

This is not the desired output, because 1, 2 and 3 are all in col x.

What formula should I use instead to get the output

```
1
6
4
```

from the table above?

Formula based answers only please, and thanks in advance for your help.